# DNSmasq configuration in multiple network

Tags: networking, router, vpn, dns, dnsmasq

I have my local network configured with custom DNS setting so I can connect to all my home network machines using their domains instead of IP. My router is providing it's own DNS server so all machines use it by default and it works pretty well.

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv

no-resolv

no-poll

server=/home/
domain=home
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4

interface=tap0
interface=lan

listen-address=10.10.0.1,10.10.1.2,127.0.0.1

host-record=machine1.home,10.10.0.101
host-record=machine2.home,10.10.0.102
host-record=machine3.home,10.10.0.103
host-record=machine4.home,10.10.0.104
```

Server is listening on local network on address 10.10.0.1, sharing DNS to VPN machine through 10.10.1.2 and also for local connections 127.0.0.1.

Now I'm trying to configure my work dns server so I can use my local network addresses while connected through VPN and connect to my company hosts using company's DNS.

Unfortunately this configuration doesn't work. Here is my configuration.

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv

no-resolv

no-poll

address=/inoffice/10.0.1.10
server=/companydev.pl/10.0.1.1
server=/companydev.pl/10.0.1.7
server=10.10.1.2
listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

This configuration runs on my local machine and should allow me to connect both to local company domains using company's dns, and the rest of the addresses should be resolved by my home dns server through connected VPN.

Unfortunately my tests are failing (while trying to connect to my local network):

> ping machine1.home
>
> ping: cannot resolve machine1.home: Unknown host

But when trying to do something like this with nslookup:

> machine1.home
>
> Server:       127.0.0.1
>
> Address:  127.0.0.1#53
>
> Name: machine1.home
>
> Address: 10.10.0.101

Pings to direct IP works:

> ping 10.10.0.101
>
> PING 10.10.0.101 (10.10.0.101): 56 data bytes
>
> 64 bytes from 10.10.0.101: icmp_seq=0 ttl=63 time=67.711 ms
>
> 64 bytes from 10.10.0.101: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=65.535 ms

Comment: Still not the case. I don't want to use *machine1* and have it mapped to *machine1.home*. I simply want to be able to use my home DNS for all requests (google.com, machine1.home, superuser.com) and only for company urls use company DNS (jira.mycompanydev.com, bitbucket.mycompanydev.com).

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, I don't understand your second comment. If you have information you think will help the OP then post it as an answer and educate them. Don't hint that you might know something that might help that they don't, that is the exact opposite of the purpose of this site.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, Well if I actually tell you twice that search domains is not the case here don't insist it is. This is totally different issue.

Comment: I do not, in fact I have quit trying to help you out. As a matter of fact, I wish you all the luck in the world in finding the root of your problem.